# Suddenly can't send messages when connected with Ethernet

Tags: network, wifi, messages, ethernet

I used to be able to send messages while my Macbook Pro was connected via an adapter with an Ethernet cable. Unfortunately, that's no longer the case, even though my internet connection works fine (I've also turned off Wifi). I can only do send messages while being connected over Wifi. Is there a way to fix this?

I've already restarted my Mac and resetted the NVRAM. But to no avail.

Some additional information from the Network settings:
[image: Network settings]

Comment: disconnect an reconnect the adapter, do you get any internet on it

Comment: Are you talking about the built-in Messages app, or something else? Do you get any error messages or alerts? Does other Internet access work? How're the networks you're connecting to set up?

Comment: @Ruskes I already did that multiple times to check if it's really the Ethernet connection that's making these problems. And yes, otherwise the connection works just as normal when I turn off Wifi.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Yes, it's the built-in app. I only get an alert "Not Delivered" when I'm trying to send a message. In the Network settings, it says it's connected. I also have a Cisco active under "Filters". The firewall is inactive, Wifi turn off.

Comment: Try signing out of Messages then signing back in.

Comment: @Allan Unfortunately, that didn't work. I also needed to be connected to WiFi and disconnect from Ethernet to sign back in. I also noticed that I'm not online in Fusion 360 (I have it installed on my Mac) when connected with Ethernet. But note that I'm still receiving E-Mails in the built-in Mail app.

Comment: It appears Apple is using your WiFi hardware UUID as part of the authentication token.   Funny thing is I don’t have this issue with my iMac. Maybe it’s because my Ethernet is built in and not USB. Are you disabling WiFi when you use the USB adapter?

Comment: @Allan That's really strange. Yes, I usually have my Wifi turned off when I use my Ethernet. Maybe I should also note that I had strange issues with my Mac around the time this problem occurred. Fortunately, I was able to solve most of them by resetting my NVRAM. Unfortunately, some issues remained. Do you think reinstalling my Mac will solve this Ethernet problem?

Comment: I don’t think a reinstall will solve this.  Was messaging working with the USB Ethernet prior?

Comment: Yes, it's an issue that's appeared only recently. I haven't changed anything on my setup, either.